# What graphics card is needed and how to set up 6 monitors in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics

I would like to connect 6 monitors to my computer to form one large desktop.

I read that solutions by nVidia require Xinerama however they appear to be quite fiddly and may require editing xorg.conf.

AMD on the other hand have support 6 displays using one card with Eyefinity however there was a reported issue with AMD drivers not working on Ubuntu 16.04.

What is the simplest (no manual xorg.conf edits), reliable (non buggy) way to set up Ubuntu 16.04 with 6 monitors?

Comment: AMD graphics are not supported currently in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Is there an expected date AMD expects to release new drivers by? How buggy are the drivers on 14.04?

Comment: There is no expected date. Btw, I a.m using AMD Graphics card with Ubuntu 16.04 and am facing no problems

Comment: @CedaEI How many monitors do you have set up? Are you using the open source drivers?

Comment: I have just one monitor and yes, I am using open source drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very and dependent not only on your graphics card but also the desktop manager. If you need to use graphics cards then using gnome or KDE is not possible. With AMD on the other hand you can run 6 monitors of a single card however be prepared to pay for an additional adapter/hub.